# Can I access other model properties in my custom Jackson Serializer?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have created a custom serializer and I'm using the serializer on a property in my model using the `@JsonSerialize(using = MySerializer.class)` annotation

I have overriden serializer method from the `JsonSerializer` class.

```
@Override
public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
}
```

The output of this property depends on the value of other properties in my model, is there any way I can get access to these properties in my serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a serializer for the whole class not just one property.  You can do this with the same annotation you are already using.

Comment: Thanks, who do i get the property values that I need from the class serializer. If I have a property called 'id' is there a way to get the value for that field and write it?

Comment: this explains it: http://dev.sghill.net/2012/04/how-do-i-write-jackson-json-serializer.html

Comment: I have used a custom serializer on my model class and it is writing the property value correctly now (the property value is determined by other values in the model). However, it is only writing that one property, i need it to run it's normal course and write all of the other properties in the model after my custom code has executed. My model is very big so I don't want to write custom code for every property. Any idea how I can do that?